# Formatting text in Windows Batch file and redirect to a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, text, format

I have a windows 7 batch script which launches a test app and writes the results to a result.txt file. After each test case is executed, I am parsing the outcome of each test case and appending (>> command) the result to result.txt file.

**What I need:**
I need to output the results to result.txt in pretty text format. How can I do it in batch file ?

The snippet (only two test cases here for example) of my script is as below:

```
REM 1. AboutScreenEnglishTest:
adb shell am instrument -w -r -e debug false -e class com.innovapost.stv.ui.activity.AboutScreenEnglishTest com.innovapost.stv.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner | FIND "FAILURES!!!" > NUL
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
ECHO 01. %Date%_%Time%: AboutScreenEnglishTest -- FAILED* >> %RESULTFILENAME%
) else (
ECHO 01. %Date%_%Time%: AboutScreenEnglishTest -- PASSED >> %RESULTFILENAME%
)

REM 2. AboutScreenFrancaisTest:
adb shell am instrument -w -r -e debug false -e class com.innovapost.stv.ui.activity.AboutScreenFrancaisTest com.innovapost.stv.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner | FIND "FAILURES!!!" > NUL
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
ECHO 02. %Date%_%Time%: AboutScreenFrancaisTest -- FAILED* >> %RESULTFILENAME%
) else (
ECHO 02. %Date%_%Time%: AboutScreenFrancaisTest -- PASSED >> %RESULTFILENAME%
)
```

This gives me the **actual result.txt** file output as below:

```
    Automated Test launched at: 2018-03-16_23:44:47.19 
    -------Package push and installation------------------------------------------
    2018-03-16_23:44:47.21: Pushing UiTest.apk to Test Phone 
    2018-03-16_23:44:59.85: Installation of UiTest.apk -- SUCCESS 
    -------End of package push and installation-----------------------------------

    Test starts here...
    No. Time of test            Test case title           Result
    --- ----------------------- ----------------------    ------
    01. 2018-03-16_23:45:23.24: AboutScreenEnglishTest -- PASSED 
    02. 2018-03-16_23:45:34.36: AboutScreenFrancaisTest -- PASSED 
    03. 2018-03-16_23:45:44.69: DebugScreenEnglishTest -- PASSED 
    04. 2018-03-16_23:45:56.23: DebugScreenFrancaisTest -- PASSED 
    05. 2018-03-16_23:46:08.67: LoadDetailsEnglishTest -- FAILED* 
    06. 2018-03-16_23:46:20.74: LoadDetailsFrancaisTest -- FAILED* 
    07. 2018-03-16_23:46:35.64: LoadServiceEnglishTest -- PASSED 
    08. 2018-03-16_23:46:53.54: LoadServiceFrancaisTest -- PASSED 
    09. 2018-03-16_23:47:06.25: LoadServiceInfoEnglishTest -- FAILED* 
    10. 2018-03-16_23:47:20.42: LoadServiceInfoFrancaisTest -- FAILED* 
    11. 2018-03-16_23:47:32.47: LoginEnglishTest -- PASSED 
    12. 2018-03-16_23:47:46.65: LoginFrancaisTest -- PASSED 
    13. 2018-03-16_23:47:58.66: MenuScreenEnglishTest -- PASSED 
    14. 2018-03-16_23:48:12.67: MenuScreenFrancaisTest -- PASSED 
    15. 2018-03-16_23:48:27.14: Training_LoadDetailsEnglishTest -- FAILED* 
    16. 2018-03-16_23:48:43.96: Training_LoadDetailsFrancaisTest -- FAILED* 
    17. 2018-03-16_23:49:03.54: Training_LoadServiceEnglishTest -- PASSED 
    18. 2018-03-16_23:49:23.52: Training_LoadServiceFrancaisTest -- PASSED 
    19. 2018-03-16_23:49:38.96: Training_LoadServiceInfoEnglishTest -- FAILED* 
    20. 2018-03-16_23:50:33.62: Training_LoadserviceInfoFrancaisTest -- FAILED*
```

But I would like the **result.txt** should looks like this. (Note that, the 'Test case title' length varies from test case to case, and my test app is incrementally including new test cases every day):

```
Automated Test launched at: 2018-03-16_23:44:47.19 
-------Package push and installation------------------------------------------
2018-03-16_23:44:47.21: Pushing UiTest.apk to Test Phone 
2018-03-16_23:44:59.85: Installation of UiTest.apk -- SUCCESS 
-------End of package push and installation-----------------------------------

Test starts here...
No. Time of test            Test case title                      Result
--- ----------------------- ----------------------               ---------
01. 2018-03-16_23:45:23.24: AboutScreenEnglishTest               -- PASSED 
02. 2018-03-16_23:45:34.36: AboutScreenFrancaisTest              -- PASSED 
03. 2018-03-16_23:45:44.69: DebugScreenEnglishTest               -- PASSED 
04. 2018-03-16_23:45:56.23: DebugScreenFrancaisTest              -- PASSED 
05. 2018-03-16_23:46:08.67: LoadDetailsEnglishTest               -- FAILED* 
06. 2018-03-16_23:46:20.74: LoadDetailsFrancaisTest              -- FAILED* 
07. 2018-03-16_23:46:35.64: LoadServiceEnglishTest               -- PASSED 
08. 2018-03-16_23:46:53.54: LoadServiceFrancaisTest              -- PASSED 
09. 2018-03-16_23:47:06.25: LoadServiceInfoEnglishTest           -- FAILED* 
10. 2018-03-16_23:47:20.42: LoadServiceInfoFrancaisTest          -- FAILED* 
11. 2018-03-16_23:47:32.47: LoginEnglishTest                     -- PASSED 
12. 2018-03-16_23:47:46.65: LoginFrancaisTest                    -- PASSED 
13. 2018-03-16_23:47:58.66: MenuScreenEnglishTest                -- PASSED 
14. 2018-03-16_23:48:12.67: MenuScreenFrancaisTest               -- PASSED 
15. 2018-03-16_23:48:27.14: Training_LoadDetailsEnglishTest      -- FAILED* 
16. 2018-03-16_23:48:43.96: Training_LoadDetailsFrancaisTest     -- FAILED* 
17. 2018-03-16_23:49:03.54: Training_LoadServiceEnglishTest      -- PASSED 
18. 2018-03-16_23:49:23.52: Training_LoadServiceFrancaisTest     -- PASSED 
19. 2018-03-16_23:49:38.96: Training_LoadServiceInfoEnglishTest  -- FAILED* 
20. 2018-03-16_23:50:33.62: Training_LoadserviceInfoFrancaisTest -- FAILED*
```

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand your problem... If you want that the `ECHO` commands include spaces at certain places in order to align the last column, why you don't just include them? `ECHO 01. %Date%_%Time%: AboutScreenEnglishTest               -- PASSED >> %RESULTFILENAME%` In previous example there are 15 spaces between `AboutScreenEnglishTest` and `-- PASSED`

Comment: Thanks Aacini for trying a solution for my problem. Magoo gave a solution and it works.

Comment: Well, imagine that you have a series of _numbers_ (like `22`, `25`, etc) you want to add to another one, but you want that the added number be a constant, like `37`. You may do that in this way: `set /A add=(22+40)%%37+1`, that is, take the base number `22`, add a large number `40`, discard the excess from `37` and adjust by `+1`; the final result is always `37`. **Or** you may do it this way: `set /A add=37`. Which method you would use?  **;)**  I don't understand _the reason_ to use the complicated method if you may just write `37` (_characters_, adding spaces) instead of `22`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set "spaces=                                            "

REM 1. AboutScreenEnglishTest:

set "Testname=AboutScreenEnglishTest"
set "testnumber=01"

call :report

REM 2. AboutScreenFrancaisTest:

set "Testname=AboutScreenFrancaisTest"
set "testnumber=02"

call :report

....
goto :eof

:report
adb shell am instrument -w -r -e debug false -e class com.innovapost.stv.ui.activity.%testname% com.innovapost.stv.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner | FIND "FAILURES!!!" > NUL

if %errorlevel% == 0 (set "result=FAILED*"
 ) else (set "result=PASSED")

set "reportfor=%testname%%spaces%"

ECHO %testnumber%. %Date%_%Time%: %reportfor:~0,30% -- %result% >> %RESULTFILENAME%

goto :eof
```

would be my approach, appending a goodly number of spaces after the testname, then taking the first 30 characters of the result to output. I didn't count the actual number you are using. Adjust to suit.

Comment: Thanks Magoo for your solution. It works. Regards. /jamil.